# Memory increase very fast when i draw canvas use kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I'm creating a game use HTML5 and kineticjs lib. I use Nodejs to start server. The code:

```
function animate() {
  newDraw()

  // Request a new animation frame using Paul Irish's shim
  window.requestAnimFrame(animate);
};

function newDraw()
{

  if(typeof localPlayer != 'undefined') {

       var layernew = new Kinetic.Layer();
       var stg = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 500,
          height: 300
        });

      var data = localPlayer.newdraw();
      layernew.add(new Kinetic.Text(data.Text))
      layernew.add(new Kinetic.Rect(data.rect))

      stg.add(layernew)

  }
}
```

inside requestAnimationFrame.js file

```
// shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 100);
          };
})();
```

it work normally, but the memory increase very fast => the firefox browser is crashed.
please help me fix this bug.
thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is:**

You are creating additional stages+layers+elements during each animation loop.

Soon you will have hundreds+ of objects all taking up memory.

**Instead:**

Create the stage+layer+text+rect once before the animation begins.

Then manipulate the existing text+rect in each animation loop using the various object.set... commands.